# Android login page throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am trying to create a login page.  My research has given me the following code, but I keep getting a java.lang.NullPointerException at line 29.  I have tried to research the answer myself but have just ended up very confused.  Can someone help me understand what I am missing please?

LOGINTESTERACTIVITY class

```
package com.b00512756.Logintester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class LogintesterActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtUserName;
EditText txtPassword;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
        Toast.makeText(LogintesterActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else{
        Toast.makeText(LogintesterActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

}
});       
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow>
<TextView 
android:text="User Name: " 
android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:id="@+id/txtUname" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
<TextView 
android:text="Password: " 
android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>


<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:id="@+id/txtPwd" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:password="true">
</EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
<Button
android:text="Cancel" 
android:id="@+id/btnCancel" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>


<Button
android:text="Login" 
android:id="@+id/btnLogin" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>


</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.b00512756.Logintester"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".LogintesterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Error Log:

```
04-29 15:36:41.570: WARN/dalvikvm(690): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.b00512756.Logintester/com.b00512756.Logintester.LogintesterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at com.b00512756.Logintester.LogintesterActivity.onCreate(LogintesterActivity.java:29)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 15:36:41.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Many thanks,
Richy

Comment: What is the statement at Line 29 in your LogintesterActivity class?

Comment: I do not know how to turn on the line numbers in Eclipse. 29 is btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { – Richy 16 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it in a debugger. Set a breakpoint at line 29, and inspect the values of your variables at that point.  Work out which one is null that shouldn't be, then look back to where it was set, and try to work out why it might have been set to null.

Also, try commenting out line 29, and see what happens.

My suspicion is your layout isn't loading correctly for some reason, but I'm not sure what that reason would be.  Might be helpful for you to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that `btnLogin` is NULL.

Maybe you can add something like `assertNotNull(bthLogin);` after this line in your code: `btnLogin = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);`

Would be more helpful if you post what is at Line 29 in your code though.

Comment: I do not know how to turn on the line numbers in Eclipse. 29 is btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing one of the 2 `btnLogin` names to another name?

You have 2 different objects with the same name: `btnLogin`

Comment: Thank you everyone - I got it working.  Turns out it was an XML issue to do with the TableLayout.  I changes it to LinearLayout and everything seems to work fine for some reason....Many thanks again :)

Comment: `android:layout_column="1"` Maybe if you have this line on each `Textview` or `Button` etc could fix it.